# getElementById doesn't return what it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I am trying to show which users have AdBlock and pass this information to Piwik but it seems to fail. It just shows like everyone got AdBlock enabled..

Here is the code I am using:

```
function _abpde() {
  if (document.getElementById("AdDiv")==null || document.getElementById("AdDiv").offsetHeight<=0) {
    _paq.push(['setCustomVariable',1,"AdBlock","Enabled","page"]);
  } else {
    _paq.push(['setCustomVariable',1,"AdBlock","Disabled","page"]);
  }
}
window.onload=_abpde();
```

And I am ussing the div:

`<div class="AdDiv" id="AdDiv">&nbsp;asd</div>`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

PS: When I try to remove the `document.getElementById("AdDiv")==null` the whole script fails and it doesn't even count visits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload=_abpde();
```

should be

```
window.onload=_abpde;
```

`()` **makes the function execute immediately**.

Comment: Ah thank you mate! That did solve a few problems, it still doesn't count users as it should though but that is another problem :P